# Angular diameter of a particle outside of the observable universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, geometry

"Angular diameter" and "apparent size" seem to be used [interchangeably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter) in cosmology. But if an object is outside of the observable universe, then isn't it no longer "apparent", yet it would still have an angular diameter?

Perhaps, the two measures diverge when the apparent size of a particle drops below the Planck length?

Is one discrete and the other continuous?

Comment: If something is outside the *observable* universe you cannot, by definition, measure an angular diameter for it.

Comment: But couldn't we estimate that a great attractor type object that was outside of the observable universe would have some non-zero angular diameter, yet it would still be correct to say it had zero apparent size? Or are the terms "angular diameter" and "apparent angular diameter" the same thing?